# Vim comma command keys

Tags: vim

I downloaded this vimrc file.
It contains entries for mapping comma seperated keys to certain commands.
ie:

```
map ,e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
```

What i can't figure out is how to run these commands in Vim.

How to i run ",e"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would just type `,` and then `e`. To verify that it's actually being mapped, you can use the command `:map ,e`.

Comment: slight tweak to this ckeck is 

:verbose map ,e

This will give you the line it has been set

Answer (score 7):

If you use these maps, you'll also want to use

```
nnoremap ,, ,
```

So you can have the <kbd>,</kbd> functionality (repeat latest `fFtT` motion, but in the opposite direction).  This is occasionally useful, though not as useful as that edit file in current file's directory map you have there.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then type `,e`

The <kbd>ESC</kbd> will confirm you are out of insert mode (if you entered it)

Answer (score 3):

just type it

```
,e
```

thats it, since the map is a normal mapping, it ought to work in normal, visual and operator pending mode. see

```
:h 40.1
```

in vim, for the help on map modes